# Add a flag column in a union Oracle SQL Query?

Tags: sql, oracle, union

Good morning,

My most recent data quandary involves me needing to add in a flag column in an Oracle SQL Union Query. The query syntax is simple:

```
SELECT 
  tblA.*
FROM tblA
  INNER JOIN tblB ON tblA.fldA = tblB.fldA

UNION ALL

SELECT
  tblA.*
FROM tblA
  INNER JOIN tblB on tblA.fldA = tblB.fldB
```

Thus, what I am looking for is: IF in the Union query it the row comes from the second half `(INNER JOIN tblB on tblA.fldA = tblB.fldB)`, for there to be a flag. I imagine adding a column called "Flag" and having a "Y" appear if it came from the second part of the Union query.

Is this achievable?

Also, I apologize for not responding immediately. I will be without internet for  a few hours. I would appreciate and welcome any insight as I continue to learn :) Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
SELECT 
  tblA.*, 'N' as FLAG
FROM tblA
  INNER JOIN tblB ON tblA.fldA = tblB.fldA

UNION ALL

SELECT
  tblA.*, 'Y' as FLAG
FROM tblA
  INNER JOIN tblB on tblA.fldA = tblB.fldB
```

Comment: is FLAG a datatype in this case, or an alias name? If I am going to put this union into a subquery to reference later, can I reference "FLAG" as the column name, or is that a datatype for the column?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the column:

```
SELECT tblA.*, 'from first part' as flag
FROM tblA
  INNER JOIN tblB ON tblA.fldA = tblB.fldA

UNION ALL

SELECT  tblA.*, 'from second part'
FROM tblA
  INNER JOIN tblB on tblA.fldA = tblB.fldB
```

Comment: is FLAG a datatype in this case, or an alias name? If I am going to put this union into a subquery to reference later, can I reference "FLAG" as the column name, or is that a datatype for the column?

Comment: It's an alias for that column

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that additional scanning of table A is a best way, especially if table B have records with fldA = fldB. Maybe you're in need of something like this

```
select 
  a.*, 
  decode(a.fldA, b.fldA, 'Y', 'N') first_match,
  decode(a.fldA, b.fldB, 'Y', 'N') second_match
from tblA a 
inner join tblB b on (a.fldA in (coalesce(b.fldA, -1), coalesce(b.fldB, -1)))
```